# Laravel route not defined in redirect

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am getting a route not defined error while using Laravel, when I have my route defined in web.php as shown below:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');
```

i am redirecting to the route from the code below

```
public function store()
{
        auth()->logout();

        return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

The auth() code works, but when the redirect is called I get the error 'Route [home] not defined.' Does anyone know how I could solve this error. Any help would be great

Comment: did you clear your route cache?

Comment: as @Aless55 said try to clear route cach 

`php artisan route:clear`

Comment: I have cleared the route cache, but the error is still present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to just return the view with different path.

```
Route::get('/test', function () {  
    return view('home');
});
```